# yum + how to ignore when repo not exists?

Tags: rhel, yum, repository

we need to run yum clean all on all machines 
but some machines have the repo - pgdg94 and some not

so when we run this:

```
yum clean all --disablerepo=pgdg94
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.


Error getting repository data for pgdg94, repository not found
```

we get error when repo - pgdg94 not exist

is it possible to tell yum , ignore when repo not exists?

Comment: Shalom yael, nochal ledaber ba chet kan legabei a'voda?

Comment: So you want to clean yum cache but not the cache for pgdg94? Otherwise you could just run `yum clean all`.

Comment: yes , without  pgdg94

Comment: @yael →  Simple : »»This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management.«« ... I.e. when you are not paying for a subscription :  No packages can be installed. Alternative : Migrate the OS / the repo to the free version "Redhat CentOS" https://gist.github.com/dcode/5642af68166ac8bb471a **,,,,** https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/MigrationGuide