# yum + how to identify that all repo verified successfully

Tags: rhel, yum, repository

I need yum cli command that can verifyed the helthcheck of all repo in my linux machine

I have try the yum repo
but exit code still 0 ( IN SPITE WE HAVE ERROR )

```
yum repolist


https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/9.4/redhat/rhel-7Server-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: ddownload.postgresql.org; Name or service not known"
Trying other mirror.
insr/primary_db                                                                                                                                           |  23 kB  00:00:00
pkg/primary_db                                                                                                                                           |  29 kB  00:00:00
local/primary_db                                                                                                                                                      | 3.6 MB  00:00:00

# echo $?
0
```

Comment: not answer on my question , I need cli to verify the repo ( like health check )  , we can do yum repolist all | grep -i errno , but this way not covered all problems

Comment: Then just use `yum repolist -v` or `yum repoinfo`.

Comment: ok , but do you have solution to my previous question - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/428052/yum-how-to-ignore-when-repo-not-exists

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make `yum repolist` exit with a non-zero exit code on errors, you have to use *verbose* mode and use either

```
yum repolist -v
```

or

```
yum repoinfo
```

From the man page of `yum`.

> ...One last special feature of repolist, is that if you are in non-verbose mode then yum will  ignore  any repo  errors  and  output  the information it can get...